# Each simulation of normal distribution is the same (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, simulation, random

I write a code to simulate a normal distribution in C++. But each time it seems the result is the same.  My question is what't the reason of this phenomenon and How to fix it?  I never have this problem with Python. Any references are very appreciated.

```
// Simulation.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<random>

void main(){

     // create default engine as source of randomness
     // The maxtime we do expriements is 10000
     // Record to the sum of the maxtimes sample
    std::default_random_engine dre; 
    const int maxtimes = 10000;
    double sum = 0.0 ;
    // Generate the normal distribution witn mean 0 and variaiton 1.
    std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.0, 1.0);
    // Output the result and Record their sum. 
    for( int i=0; i<maxtimes; ++i)
      {

        double x = distribution(dre);
        std::cout << x << ":";
        sum +=x; 
        x =0.0; 
      }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::cout <<" The average sum is: " << sum/10000 <<std::endl; 
  }
```

My code runs in visual C++ 2010.

Comment: Please pay attention to formatting. This is what the preview panel is for.

Answer (score 3):

You're constructing the `default_random_engine` from the same seed every time: Since you aren't giving it a seed to construct with, it simply uses the default, which is the same every run, so you get the same "random" numbers each run. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/linear_congruential_engine/linear_congruential_engine/

Use [random_device](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/random_device/) to seed the generator.

```
std::default_random_engine dre(std::random_device()());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
std::random_device mch;
std::default_random_engine generator(mch());
std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.