# Why c++11 std::normal_distribution return same pattern when called from a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, normal-distribution

I want to introduce Gaussian noise to a signal. I looked into several examples of how to use C++11 `std::normal_distribution` and I was able to achieve the expected random result using this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32890945/3424478

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>

int main() {
    // Example data
    std::vector<double> data = {1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.};

    // Define random generator with Gaussian distribution
    const double mean = 0.0;
    const double stddev = 0.1;
    auto dist = std::bind(std::normal_distribution<double>{mean, stddev},
                          std::mt19937(std::random_device{}()));

    // Add Gaussian noise
    for (auto& x : data) {
        x = x + dist();
    }

    // Output the result, for demonstration purposes
    std::copy(begin(data), end(data), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This work perfectly while I call `dist()` several times from `main()` and also works fine with different vectors but as soon as I move the code to a function  it always return the same constant noise pattern, I want to call this function to modify the reference signal and assign it to different arrays or vectors. Here is my code:

```
void AddGaussianNoiseToPixel(std::array<short int, N_SLICES>& pixel_array, const std::array<short int, N_SLICES>& reference_pixel)
{
    const float mean   = 0.0;
    const float stddev = 2.0;
    auto dist = std::bind(std::normal_distribution<float>{mean, stddev},
                          std::mt19937(std::random_device{}()));

    for (const auto& slice : reference_pixel) 
    {
        pixel_array[&slice-&reference_pixel[0]] = rint(slice+dist());
    }
}
```

I read a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22921927/3424478 where this suppose to be happening due to the seed passed to the random generator but that's not the case since I'm passing `std::random_device{}()` to the random engine`std::mt19937()`

**EDIT:**

I'm using MinGW-W64-builds-4.3.5 in Windows 7

Comment: What platform and compiler?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce (with `g++ 8.1.0`). [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a8b825292b66b97) Did I miss something?

Comment: Is this using MinGW?

Comment: Also `std::bind` is slower than using a `lambda`. Also creating and initializing the random generator every time you call the function is going to be less efficient than initializing the random generator once and passing it in to the function.

Comment: Don't create a new generator and distribution each time you call your function.  Use static variables.

Comment: from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device): 
std::random_device may be implemented in terms of an implementation-defined pseudo-random number engine if a non-deterministic source (e.g. a hardware device) is not available to the implementation. **In this case each std::random_device object may generate the same number sequence**.

Comment: watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DPkyvkMkk8) video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely related to a [feature/bug in mingw](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/338/) that makes `std::random_device` deterministic. You can circumvent this by adding another source of entropy, e.g. current time:

```
  uint64_t seed = std::random_device{}() |
    std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
```

However, a better solution is to use only one engine and distribution object. A simple way to do that is to use a static variable within a new function.